# Neoload how to connect tibco server. Getting Cannot instantiate class: om.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory Error

Tags: tibco-ems, neoload

I am using Neoload for performance testing but getting the

> Blockquote

the following error while connecting to the Tibco server.

```
Could not create JNDI API initial context: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: om.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: om.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory]java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: om.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory
```

I am using the following parameters

```
initialContextFactory (required):  com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory
providerURL (required): tibjmsnaming://10.106.29.215:5222
connectionFactory (required): QueueConnectionFactory
destination (required): myqueuename
```

Answer (score 0):

tibjms.jar is missing in the class path.

Please check the class path again .